# Android: scaling button widths proportionally to screen width

Tags: android, view, width, android-relativelayout

I have a group of Buttons which have varying widths, and I'm inserting them programmatically into a RelativeLayout (horizontal orientation). I'm trying to scale the width of the buttons so that they take up the entire width of the visible screen. The important thing is, the buttons' widths should remain proportionally the same to each other; just stretched or shrunk to take up the entire screen width.

I'm setting the initial width of each button to a discrete, unrelated int value. In most cases, the group of buttons only take up part of the screen width. I'd like to stretch the buttons' widths, to take up the entire screen width, while retaining the button widths' proportions, relative to each other.

Can someone give me some assistance in calculating the new, adjusted widths of the buttons? I have no problem getting the screen width in pixels, and I can also easily get the total widths (in pixels) of all the buttons. I just need to scale each buttons' width, and I have to do it programmatically; not in the xml. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out (derp). Just set each button's width to (original button width) * ((screen width pixels) / (total buttons' widths)). The trick was getting an actual decimal value out of the quotient above.